# Name instance tag not applied when calling run-instance JSON in python awscli

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

i'm experiencing a strange issue with using of AWS CLI tools (awscli python module awscli-1.11.136, awscli-1.11.177). When calling 'run-instances' action with *--cli-input-json* argument, instance is not Tagged with the Name tag i specify in a call. Example of the call: `aws ec2 run-instances --cli-input-json file://test-1c.json`.

The *test-1c.json* contains following *TagSpecifications*:

```
"TagSpecifications": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "test-1c"
                }
            ],
            "ResourceType": "volume",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "test-1c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Volume is properly tagged with the specified *Name* tag, but instance is not.

When calling the same using command line arguments, it works properly:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \                                             
--image-id ami-123456 \
--instance-type t2.micro \
--placement AvailabilityZone=eu-central-1b \
--security-group-ids sg-123456 \
--subnet-id subnet-123456 \
--private-ip-address 172.31.0.1 \
--tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=test-1c}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=name,Value=test-1c}]'{code}
```

Is there a bug in the JSON's run-instances awscli python module functionality or am i doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your JSON structure.

Your `TagSpecifications` array only has a single tag object in it. That one object has 2 `ResourceType` and 2 `Tags` properties, the 2nd of which (for the volume) is overriding the 1st (for the instance). This is the cause for the failure.

Add missing `},{` into your structure before `"ResourceType": "volume",`

Such as

```
"TagSpecifications": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "test-1c"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "ResourceType": "volume",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "test-1c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```